# Solving a constructor problem that uses static polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a base class that allows the option to inherit from several other classes.

```
template<class T>
class Option1 {
protected:
    T m_optional_1;
public:
    void setOptional1(const unsigned int); // Initialized from a size
    T getOptional1() const;
};


template<class T>
class Option2 {
protected:
    T m_optional_2;
public:
    void setOptional2(T); // NOT initialized from a size
    T getOptional2() const;
};


template<class T, class ...Mixins>
class Standard : public Mixins... {
protected:
    T m_required;
public:
    Standard(const unsigned int); // Initialized from a size

    void setRequired(const unsigned int);
    T getRequired() const;
};
```

From this one could call the following.

```
Standard<std::vector<int>, Option1<std::vector<float>>, Option2<float(*)(float)>> uniqueA 
= Standard<std::vector<int>, Option1<std::vector<float>>, Option2<float(*)(float)>>(3);

Standard<std::vector<float>, Option1<std::vector<int>>> uniqueB 
= Standard<std::vector<float>, Option1<std::vector<int>>>(5);

Standard<std::vector<int>> uniqueC = Standard<std::vector<int>>(0);
```

Great, I now have optional class member variables depending on the declared template but can I initialize them through the constructor?

For example if I called the below.

```
Standard<std::vector<int>, Option1<std::vector<float>>, Option2<float(*)(float)>> uniqueA 
= Standard<std::vector<int>, Option1<std::vector<float>>, Option2<float(*)(float)>>(5);
```

I would expect `uniqueA` to hold a `std::vector<int>` of size `5` in `m_required`, `m_optional_1` to hold a `std::vector<float>` of size 5 and `m_optional_2` to be an uninitialized function pointer of type `float(*)(float)`.

How could I achieve this, I can't see how to write a flexible constructor for `Standard`.

Attempt 1:

```
template<class T, class ...Mixins>
Standard<T>::Standard(const unsigned int size) :  {
    setOptional1(size);
    setRequired(size); // Error no guarantee Option1 is being inherited from 
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
// Create constructor for Option1
template<class T, class ...Mixins>
Standard<T>::Standard(const unsigned int size) : Mixins...(size)  { 
    // Error no such constructor exists for Option2 and to create one would be meaningless
    setRequired(size); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to silently skip initialization for option types that do not have a matching constructor? How about move-constructing each option from a provided instance instead?

Comment: @Quentin Could you elaborate? What do you mean by a provided instance?

Comment: Something like `Standard s{std::vector<int>(5), Option1<std::vector<float>>{5}, Option2<float(*)(float)>{}}`, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this would involve storing the 'sub-classes' instead of creating a singleton which would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The idea is just to pass each parameter to the corresponding `Mixin`, and let them move-construct themselves. I don't see any singleton in your question, but I don't think this would prevent making one in any way.

Comment: Please ignore what I said about a singleton. What I meant was in your  suggestion ```Standard``` is move constructed with each ```Mixin```. ```Standard``` would therefore not be a child class of anything. I want ```Standard``` to have all the methods and member variables of each ```Mixin``` instead of accessing them through a member variable. Perhaps I've misunderstood you but it sounds to me like your suggesting to remove all class dependencies which wouldn't be static polymorphism.

Comment: No, you can achieve that initialization syntax while keeping the `Mixins` as base classes. The only thing that changes is that now the caller passes parameters for each mixin explicitly, rather than a single set of parameters which is then dispatched selectively as you originally asked (which seems a bit too implicit to my taste, but definitely doable as well).

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not implicitly skip constructors for optional mixins that don't match, and instead let the caller initialize each mixin explicitly:

```
template<class T>
class Option1 {
    // ...
public:
    // Constructor(s)
    Option1(const unsigned int) { }
    // ...
};


template<class T>
class Option2 {
    // ...
public:
    // Constructor(s)
    Option2(T) { }
    // ...
};

template<class T, class ...Mixins>
class Standard : public Mixins... {
    // ...
public:

    // Forward each argument to the corresponding mixin
    template <class RequiredArg, class... OptionArgs>
    Standard(RequiredArg &&requiredArg, OptionArgs &&... optionArgs)
    : Mixins(std::forward<OptionArgs>(optionArgs))...
    , m_required(std::forward<RequiredArg>(requiredArg)) { }

    // ...
};

// Deduction guide to simplify construction
template <class Required, class... Mixins>
Standard(Required, Mixins...) -> Standard<Required, Mixins...>;

// ...

// Usage
Standard s{
    std::vector<int>(5),
    Option1<std::vector<float>>{5},
    Option2<float(*)(float)>{func}
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NbQ1nVDzvpRV5MHx)

---

To answer your original question, one can use a layer of SFINAE to try and construct each `Mixin` from the size, or default-construct it if that isn't possible.

```
template<class T>
class Option1 {
public:
    Option1(const unsigned int) { }
};

template<class T>
class Option2 {
public:
    Option2() { }
};

template<class T, class ...Mixins>
class Standard : public Mixins... {
protected:
    T m_required;
public:
    Standard(const unsigned int size)
    : Mixins(make_mixin<Mixins>(size))...
    , m_required(size) { }
    
private:
    template <class Mixin>
    static auto make_mixin(const unsigned int size) -> decltype(Mixin(size)) { return Mixin(size); }
    template <class Mixin>
    static auto make_mixin(...) -> Mixin { return Mixin(); }
};
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qLuNaIvHByEahjit)

In your particular case, maybe the simplest solution is just to give `Option2` a dummy constructor taking the size (possibly `private` and be`friend`ing `Standard`).